# Deleting files by way of the terminal where files have a certain keyword

Tags: command-line, git, trash

**UPDATE**

Status of the process for the command `rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/files/` has been set to `Very High`. Command was initiated at 0745 today and is still running. CPU Time is current 53 seconds at 0955, memory is constant at 52.0 miB. Status goes between `Running` and `Uninteruptible`

---

I opened up nano yesterday to just look at a file and noticed that inside of my home directory I have a very large amount of files in there that can be deleted. They are there because awhile back I accidentally turned my home directory into a git repo. I undid this, but I want to clean up the mess that I could only see when viewing the folder when searching for a file using nano.

I have this same problem in my trash bin where I have so many files in it from bad git repos that I cannot just click on the trash bin and click empty bin all 8 gigs plus the swap get used up and nothing gets deleted.

How can I delete files from the terminal where the files meet a certain pattern?
I have tried the following command:

`rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/Files/*`

`rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/info/*`

and I eventually some time later get a message that there are just to many files and it does not delete.

I would like to say delete all files that start or end with some pattern like `.quo` or whatever they might be. To sum it up:

How do I list all the files so that I can at least start finding some begining or ending patterns to identify those for deletion
How do I use that pattern to delete them?

Comment: Use the find command: `find /path/to/directory/ -name *pattern*`. If that lists the right files, delete them with `find /path/to/directory/ -name *pattern* -exec rm {} \;`. The exec option exectutes the rm command, where {} is substituted by the filename. The \; bit signifies the end of the rm command.

Comment: Thank you I will try this tonight when I get home and let you know what happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you have too many files which means that `*` in your `rm` command is expanded to a list that is longer than the limit ([ARG_MAX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118200/22222)). So, to get around this you have various options:

1. Give `rm` only *some* of the files:

   ```
   rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/Files/*.quo
   ```
2. Delete the directory containing the files, this avoids listing the files altogether:

   ```
   rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/Files/
   ```
3. Use `find`:

   ```
   find ~/.local/share/Trash/Files/ -delete
   ```

   or, for non-GNU `find`:

   ```
   find ~/.local/share/Trash/Files/ -exec rm {} +
   ```
4. Use a shell loop

   ```
   for file in  ~/.local/share/Trash/Files/*; do rm "$file"; done
   ```

Comment: as of right now it has been running for 20 minutes, I went to the path ~/.local/share/Trash and did rm -rm files will update later

Comment: the following command `rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/files/` has been running for two hours now, when I go to process properties it says the CPU use is 0% and CPU time is 48 seconds, resident memory remains constant at 52.5 mb, status switches between `Uninterubtible` and `running`

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator that's fine. There's no reason for that command to use significant CPU or memory and if you are deleting several gigabytes of files it can take _ages_. You can also try running `rm -rfv ~/.local/share/Trash/Files/` which will list the files being deleted (the `-v` means "verbose"). That way, you can be sure it's doing _something_.

Comment: Thank you, did not know that. I'm going to stop the current process and use that one instead and report back

Comment: no need, it just finished, thank you for your help i really appreciate it.